# How to launch Brackets from terminal with sudo privileges?

Tags: command-line, html, css

How to launch Brackets from terminal with root privileges within some directory?

Comment: Why with `sudo`. That's a bad idea.

Comment: please elaborate or provide a ref why that's a bad idea? Some of us, not a geek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sudo`:

```
sudo -i brackets
```

It will launch as a root instance. Make sure to use `-i`, it prevents root owning any of your home folder.

To launch in a certain directory, first `cd` to that directory, like this:

```
cd /path/to/folder
```

Then launch it with the same command:

```
sudo -i brackets
```

Comment: He wants to run as root, let him, what's wrong with this?

Comment: Neutrall-ed, with note using root with awareness, we can cause unnecessary problems but we are the owner of our PC.